# how to call php file in html <div>

Tags: php, html

```
 <div id = "info">
 <div class="portlet-body">

  <?php include('mysqlreader.php');?>
 </div>
```

I want to call php file (mysqlreader.php) in div, mysqlreader.php is in same repository where my actual file is, I tried above mentioned code. But it is not working. what is the proper way to call .php file in html.

**Edit:** The file's extension I am using for this, is in fact `.php`

Comment: You call a PHP file in PHP, not in html.

Comment: Did you name your file `.html` or `.php`? It *has* to be named `.php` unless you've changed your config to run HTML files through PHP.

Comment: **Do specify** (next time) as to what your file extension is.

Comment: my file name has .php extension

Comment: Well, I don't know why my answer got 3 downvotes, since I was correct right away and being the first to answer. I have deleted it because of that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got down vote too, for the first time. I don't know why?

Comment: People can be rather strange animals at times.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was using your answer. I revisited site, and your answer was gone

Comment: Reload the page, it's undeleted lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- I saved one of yours.

Comment: While a fairly simple question might actually be dealt with a quick code snippet, I'd say voteups are meant to indicate that a given answer also tries to indulge the OP (and any others reading) on the nature of the answer, why it is correct, why it should be done like that, etc. That being said, I did NOT issue any downvotes within this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to keep in mind, that in order to run PHP code, you must have a PHP interpreter installed on your server. Second step is that your file actually has a .php extension, otherwise the server will handle it as a simple html file (if its got an .html extension or variant).

Otherwise, your code should look as follows:

```
<div id = "info">
    <div class="portlet-body">
     <?php
     include('mysqlreader.php');
     ?>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an edit, but that's what I had in here originally.

You had forgotten a `</div>` which I should have also mentioned.

```
<div id = "info">

<div class="portlet-body">
<?php

    include('mysqlreader.php');
?>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Downvotes should be kindly retracted, [`since OP said he had used my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524904/how-to-call-php-file-in-html-div#comment39849732_25524904), but he noticed I had deleted it (because of getting multiple downvotes). Seems like I was right from the get-go. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To make use of `<?php ... ?>` your file must be treated as PHP script file first. The simplest approach is to change its name from `foo.html` to `foo.php` as `.php` files (assuming proper server config) should go thru PHP interpreter. Alternatively you can set up your httpd to treat files with other name pattern as PHP as well but the way of doing so depends on httpd used.

Comment: `foo.htnl` => `foo.html`

Answer (score 0):

whenever u want to add some php code in html u have to use php structure

```
<?php 

   //your php code
   //for including file u can use include()function
  include('your file name.php');

?>
```